# Resize columns as they are displayed - NatTable

Tags: java, swt, nattable

I have a `VerticalTextPainter` for column headers and a `TextPainter` for row headers.

Some of the columns/rows have newlines so I would like to resize the column widths and row heights to fit the content. This should only happen once when the column/row is first displayed so the user can change the widths/heights afterwards.

When scrolling quite quickly it sometimes won't resize the column/rows.

```
nattable.addOverlayPainter(new IOverlayPainter() {

    @Override
    public void paintOverlay(final GC gc, final ILayer layer) {

        for (int i = 0; i < nattable.getColumnCount(); i++) {

            final int indexByPosition = columnlayer.getColumnIndexByPosition(i);
            if (!resizedColumnsByPosition.contains(indexByPosition)) {

                resizedColumnsByPosition.add(indexByPosition);

                nattable.doCommand(new InitializeAutoResizeColumnsCommand(gridlayer, i, nattable.getConfigRegistry(), new GCFactory(nattable)));
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < nattable.getRowCount(); i++) {

            final int indexByPosition = nattable.getRowIndexByPosition(i);
            if (!resizedRowsByPosition.contains(indexByPosition)) {

                resizedRowsByPosition.add(indexByPosition);

                nattable.doCommand(new InitializeAutoResizeRowsCommand(nattable, i, nattable.getConfigRegistry(), new GCFactory(nattable)));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I've created a small example showing the problem. The height of the column header can be ignored as I'm just trying to set the width in this code.

**Complete example**

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;

import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.NatTable;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.config.AbstractRegistryConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.config.CellConfigAttributes;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.config.ConfigRegistry;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.config.IConfigRegistry;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.data.IDataProvider;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.data.convert.DefaultDisplayConverter;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.grid.GridRegion;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.grid.data.DefaultColumnHeaderDataProvider;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.grid.data.DefaultCornerDataProvider;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.grid.data.DefaultRowHeaderDataProvider;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.grid.data.DummyBodyDataProvider;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.grid.layer.ColumnHeaderLayer;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.grid.layer.CornerLayer;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.grid.layer.GridLayer;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.grid.layer.RowHeaderLayer;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.hideshow.ColumnHideShowLayer;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.layer.AbstractLayerTransform;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.layer.CompositeLayer;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.layer.DataLayer;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.layer.ILayer;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.layer.LabelStack;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.layer.cell.IConfigLabelAccumulator;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.painter.IOverlayPainter;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.painter.cell.CellPainterWrapper;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.painter.cell.ICellPainter;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.painter.cell.TextPainter;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.painter.cell.VerticalTextPainter;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.painter.cell.decorator.CustomLineBorderDecorator;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.painter.cell.decorator.LineBorderDecorator;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.painter.cell.decorator.PaddingDecorator;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.reorder.ColumnReorderLayer;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.resize.command.InitializeAutoResizeColumnsCommand;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.resize.command.InitializeAutoResizeRowsCommand;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.selection.SelectionLayer;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.style.BorderStyle;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.style.CellStyleAttributes;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.style.DisplayMode;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.style.HorizontalAlignmentEnum;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.style.Style;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.style.VerticalAlignmentEnum;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.util.GCFactory;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.util.GUIHelper;
import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.viewport.ViewportLayer;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Font;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class ExampleNatTable {

    private BodyLayerStack bodyLayer;
    private int statusColumn;
    private int statusRejected;
    private int statusInProgress;
    private boolean check = false;
    private NatTable nattable;
    private String[] summaryProperties;
    private String[] properties;
    private static final String FOO_LABEL = "FOO";
    private static final String CELL_LABEL = "Cell_LABEL";

    private final Collection < Integer > resizedColumnsByPosition = new HashSet < >();
    private final Collection < Integer > resizedRowsByPosition = new HashSet < >();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ExampleNatTable();
    }

    public ExampleNatTable() {

        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        summaryProperties = new String[100];

        for (int i = 0; i < summaryProperties.length; i++) {

            summaryProperties[i] = "s" + i;
        }

        properties = new String[100];

        for (int i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {

            properties[i] = "Column" + i;
        }

        // Setting the data layout layer
        GridData gridData = new GridData();
        gridData.heightHint = 1;
        gridData.widthHint = 1;

        IConfigRegistry configRegistry = new ConfigRegistry();

        // Body Data Provider
        IDataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider(properties.length, 55);
        bodyLayer = new BodyLayerStack(dataProvider);
        // datalayer.addConfiguration(new

        // Column Data Provider
        DefaultColumnHeaderDataProvider columnSummaryData = new DefaultColumnHeaderDataProvider(summaryProperties);
        DefaultColumnHeaderDataProvider columnData = new DefaultColumnHeaderDataProvider(properties);
        ColumnHeaderLayerStack columnSummaryLayer = new ColumnHeaderLayerStack(columnSummaryData);
        ColumnHeaderLayerStack columnlayer = new ColumnHeaderLayerStack(columnData);

        /**
     * Composite layer
     */
        final CompositeLayer columnCompositeLayer = new CompositeLayer(1, 2);
        columnCompositeLayer.setChildLayer("SUMMARY_REGION", columnSummaryLayer, 0, 0);
        columnCompositeLayer.setChildLayer("COLUMNS", columnlayer, 0, 1);

        // Row Data Provider
        DefaultRowHeaderDataProvider rowdata = new DefaultRowHeaderDataProvider(dataProvider);
        RowHeaderLayerStack rowlayer = new RowHeaderLayerStack(rowdata);

        // Corner Data Provider
        DefaultCornerDataProvider cornerdata = new DefaultCornerDataProvider(columnData, rowdata);
        DataLayer cornerDataLayer = new DataLayer(cornerdata);
        CornerLayer cornerLayer = new CornerLayer(cornerDataLayer, rowlayer, columnCompositeLayer);

        GridLayer gridlayer = new GridLayer(bodyLayer, columnCompositeLayer, rowlayer, cornerLayer);
        nattable = new NatTable(shell, gridlayer, false);

        // Change for paint
        IConfigLabelAccumulator cellLabelAccumulator = new IConfigLabelAccumulator() {
            // @Override
            @Override
            public void accumulateConfigLabels(LabelStack configLabels, int columnPosition, int rowPosition) {

                int columnIndex = bodyLayer.getColumnIndexByPosition(columnPosition);
                int rowIndex = bodyLayer.getRowIndexByPosition(rowPosition);
                if (columnIndex == 2 && rowIndex == 45) {
                    configLabels.addLabel(FOO_LABEL);
                } else if ((columnIndex == statusColumn) && (rowIndex == statusRejected) && (check == true)) {
                    configLabels.addLabel(CELL_LABEL);
                }
            }
        };
        bodyLayer.setConfigLabelAccumulator(cellLabelAccumulator);

        // nattable.addConfiguration(new DefaultNatTableStyleConfiguration());
        nattable.addConfiguration(new AbstractRegistryConfiguration() {
            // @Override
            @Override
            public void configureRegistry(IConfigRegistry configRegistry) {

                /**
         * Column Header
         */
                final Style columnHeaderStyle = new Style();

                columnHeaderStyle.setAttributeValue(CellStyleAttributes.VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT, VerticalAlignmentEnum.BOTTOM);

                columnHeaderStyle.setAttributeValue(CellStyleAttributes.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT, HorizontalAlignmentEnum.CENTER);

                configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(CellConfigAttributes.CELL_STYLE, columnHeaderStyle, DisplayMode.NORMAL, GridRegion.COLUMN_HEADER);

                final VerticalTextPainter columnHeaderPainter = new VerticalTextPainter(false, true, false);

                Display display = Display.getCurrent();
                Color blue = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE);

                final CellPainterWrapper columnHeaderDecorator = new CustomLineBorderDecorator(
                new PaddingDecorator(columnHeaderPainter, 3, 0, 3, 0), new BorderStyle(1, blue, BorderStyle.LineStyleEnum.SOLID));

                configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(CellConfigAttributes.CELL_PAINTER, columnHeaderDecorator, DisplayMode.NORMAL, GridRegion.COLUMN_HEADER);

                /**
         * Cells
         */
                final Color bgColor = GUIHelper.COLOR_WHITE;
                final Color fgColor = GUIHelper.COLOR_BLACK;
                final Color gradientBgColor = GUIHelper.COLOR_WHITE;
                final Color gradientFgColor = GUIHelper.getColor(136, 212, 215);
                final Font font = GUIHelper.DEFAULT_FONT;
                final HorizontalAlignmentEnum hAlign = HorizontalAlignmentEnum.CENTER;
                final VerticalAlignmentEnum vAlign = VerticalAlignmentEnum.MIDDLE;
                final BorderStyle borderStyle = null;
                final ICellPainter cellPainter = new LineBorderDecorator(new TextPainter(false, true, 5, true));

                configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(CellConfigAttributes.CELL_PAINTER, cellPainter);

                Style cellStyle = new Style();
                cellStyle.setAttributeValue(CellStyleAttributes.BACKGROUND_COLOR, bgColor);
                cellStyle.setAttributeValue(CellStyleAttributes.FOREGROUND_COLOR, fgColor);
                cellStyle.setAttributeValue(CellStyleAttributes.GRADIENT_BACKGROUND_COLOR, gradientBgColor);
                cellStyle.setAttributeValue(CellStyleAttributes.GRADIENT_FOREGROUND_COLOR, gradientFgColor);
                cellStyle.setAttributeValue(CellStyleAttributes.FONT, font);
                cellStyle.setAttributeValue(CellStyleAttributes.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT, hAlign);
                cellStyle.setAttributeValue(CellStyleAttributes.VERTICAL_ALIGNMENT, vAlign);
                cellStyle.setAttributeValue(CellStyleAttributes.BORDER_STYLE, borderStyle);

                configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(CellConfigAttributes.CELL_STYLE, cellStyle);

                configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(CellConfigAttributes.DISPLAY_CONVERTER, new DefaultDisplayConverter());
            }
        });

        nattable.setLayoutData(gridData);
        nattable.setConfigRegistry(configRegistry);
        nattable.configure();

        nattable.addOverlayPainter(new IOverlayPainter() {

            @Override
            public void paintOverlay(final GC gc, final ILayer layer) {

                for (int i = 0; i < nattable.getColumnCount(); i++) {

                    final int indexByPosition = columnlayer.getColumnIndexByPosition(i);
                    if (!resizedColumnsByPosition.contains(indexByPosition)) {

                        resizedColumnsByPosition.add(indexByPosition);

                        System.out.println(indexByPosition + " : " + i);

                        nattable.doCommand(new InitializeAutoResizeColumnsCommand(gridlayer, i, nattable.getConfigRegistry(), new GCFactory(nattable)));
                    }
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < nattable.getRowCount(); i++) {

                    final int indexByPosition = nattable.getRowIndexByPosition(i);
                    if (!resizedRowsByPosition.contains(indexByPosition)) {

                        resizedRowsByPosition.add(indexByPosition);

                        nattable.doCommand(new InitializeAutoResizeRowsCommand(nattable, i, nattable.getConfigRegistry(), new GCFactory(nattable)));
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();

    }

    public class DataProvider extends DummyBodyDataProvider {

        public DataProvider(int columnCount, int rowCount) {
            super(columnCount, rowCount);
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return properties.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getDataValue(int columnIndex, int rowIndex) {

            return new String("" + columnIndex + ":" + rowIndex);

        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return 55;
        }

        @Override
        public void setDataValue(int arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {

}
    }

    public class BodyLayerStack extends AbstractLayerTransform {

        private SelectionLayer selectionLayer;

        public BodyLayerStack(IDataProvider dataProvider) {
            DataLayer bodyDataLayer = new DataLayer(dataProvider);
            ColumnReorderLayer columnReorderLayer = new ColumnReorderLayer(bodyDataLayer);
            ColumnHideShowLayer columnHideShowLayer = new ColumnHideShowLayer(columnReorderLayer);
            this.selectionLayer = new SelectionLayer(columnHideShowLayer);
            ViewportLayer viewportLayer = new ViewportLayer(this.selectionLayer);
            setUnderlyingLayer(viewportLayer);
        }

        public SelectionLayer getSelectionLayer() {
            return this.selectionLayer;
        }
    }

    public class ColumnHeaderLayerStack extends AbstractLayerTransform {

        public ColumnHeaderLayerStack(IDataProvider dataProvider) {
            DataLayer dataLayer = new DataLayer(dataProvider);
            ColumnHeaderLayer colHeaderLayer = new ColumnHeaderLayer(dataLayer, ExampleNatTable.this.bodyLayer, ExampleNatTable.this.bodyLayer.getSelectionLayer());
            setUnderlyingLayer(colHeaderLayer);
        }
    }

    public class RowHeaderLayerStack extends AbstractLayerTransform {

        public RowHeaderLayerStack(IDataProvider dataProvider) {
            DataLayer dataLayer = new DataLayer(dataProvider, 50, 20);
            RowHeaderLayer rowHeaderLayer = new RowHeaderLayer(dataLayer, ExampleNatTable.this.bodyLayer, ExampleNatTable.this.bodyLayer.getSelectionLayer());
            setUnderlyingLayer(rowHeaderLayer);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried using the different layers to get the column counts and indexes but can't get this to work.

What is the correct method of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are scrolling fast, the executed commands could not match the updated state in scrolling. Probably a runtime issue as the commands in use are not really intended to work on scrolling.

I am running out of ideas to support all your requirements in autoresizing. You can have a look at the 1.6 version of the `AutoResizeHelper` and try to adapt the auto row resizing approach for columns.

Comment: Okay thank you for the help. I think it will be best to cut out the complexity and remove newlines from headers. It would be great to try out the latest version but we can't until it's released. Out of curiosity is there an estimate for when it will be released?

Comment: Well I'm trying to release in the next few weeks. Seems there are no further blocker issues despite my time to prepare everything.